# Add value to a drop down menu with a form

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to insert values in a drop down menu with a simple form? I have this drop down menu

```
<form>
  <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
    <option value="">Select a category:</option>
    <option value="movie">Movie</option>
    <option value="musik">Musik</option>
    <option value="books">Books</option>
    <option value="images">Images</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Should I use an array? I been searching the net but couldn't find anything that would help.

Comment: What does this mean? What form? How are you adding them? Client-side with Javascript?

Comment: Now I just add them in the code, I want to be able to use a simple form to add some other values.

Java script should do it, but i really dont know how

Comment: @FelipeOtarola If you want Javascript, then tag your question so instead of as PHP. Also, your comment doesn't clarify your question very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a JavaScript solution to add items to a drop down.

The HTML to use..

```
 <form>
    <select id="categories" name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
    <option value="">Select a category:</option>
    <option value="movie">Movie</option>
    <option value="musik">Musik</option>
    <option value="books">Books</option>
    <option value="images">Images</option>
    </select>
    </form>​​
```

JavaScript code...

```
var categories = document.getElementById("categories");

var newOption = document.createElement('option');
newOption.innerText = "New value";
newOption.setAttribute('value', 'newvalue');

categories.appendChild(newOption);
​
```

jQuery code... (a lot shorter)

```
$("#categories").append("<option value='newvalue'>New Value</option>");
```

Here is the JavaScript [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8hUU/) and the jQuery [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8hUU/2/) to play with!

Answer (score 1):

You could look into jQuery `append()` and `option()` with `click` event...

I've just created a working solution for you.
Don't know if this is what you was looking for, but this is how it works:
You simply just write the value and visual option name into a form text field: `value, text` which gives you this:
`<option value="value">text</option>`

```
<select id="mySelect"></select>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="text" id="string"><br>
<button id="append">Append</button>


$('#append').click(function(){
    var str = $('#string').val();
    var substr = str.split(', ');
    $('#mySelect').append( new Option(substr[0],substr[1]));
});
```

Here is a working version:  http://jsfiddle.net/SCf8m/1/